# Can not apply inline styling in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to style quotes inside posts. But whatever I do, the tags turn into characters and hence become ineffective.

The views is:

```
@login_required
def quote_reply(request, quote_id):
    tform = PostForm()
    print 'user is:' + request.user.username
    quote = Post.objects.get(pk = quote_id)
    topic_id = quote.topic_id
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id= topic_id)


    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = PostForm(request.POST)


        if post.is_valid():

            p = post.save(commit = False)
            p.topic = topic
            p.title = post.cleaned_data['title']
            p.body = '<span style="background-color: yellow; font-size:2em;">' + unicode(quote.body) + '</span>\n\n'+ post.cleaned_data['body'] #problematic line
            p.creator = request.user
            p.user_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

            if len(p.title)< 1:

                            p.title= str(request.user.username) + 'wrote:'
            p.save()

            tid = int(topic_id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/topic/%s'  % topic_id)

    else:
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = tform
        args['post'] = quote
        args['topic_id'] = topic_id
        return render_to_response('myforum/qoute_reply.html', args, 
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The relevant template part is:

```
                <ul class="forum-post-body list-unstyled list-inline">
                         <li class="col-md-2 userpanel">{{ post.creator }} <br> </li>

                         {% autoescape on %}
                         <li class="col-md-10">{{ post.body|linebreaks }} </li>
                         {% endautoescape %}
                </ul>
```

The raw html output turns out to be something like:

```
<li class="col-md-10"><p>&lt;span style=&quot;background-color: yellow; font-size:2em;&quot;&gt;This is a post</p>

<p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
```

I also tested without linebreak filter but it also  yields:

```
    <li class="col-md-10">&lt;span style=&quot;background-color: yellow; font-size:3em;&quot;&gt;This is a post

&lt;/span&gt;

And here is the reply </li>
```

Appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn `autoescape` off:

```
{% autoescape off %}
<li class="col-md-10">{{ post.body|linebreaks }} </li>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Or use the `safe` template filter and omit `autoescape` template tag:

```
<li class="col-md-10">{{ post.body|safe|linebreaks }} </li>
```

To safely embed user generated data into your html code use the [`format_html()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function.

Comment: BTW, regarding that I have `cleaned_data` in my views, is it safe to turn off autoscape at rendering?

Comment: No, it is not safe. So use the `format_html()` function to safe inclusion of the `cleaned_data` into your html code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html